# cart count not updating in mobile devices woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

i am using this code to update cart count in woocommerce to update woocommerce cart.it is working correctly in larger devices.but not working in mobile devices.anly after refresh it works.
i am attaching code below.

in functions.php this is the code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>  
    <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();       
    echo $cart_count;
    ?></span>
    
    <?php
     $fragments['#cart-count'] = ob_get_clean();     
    return $fragments;
}
```

in header.php cart section in large devices and mobile devices

```
<li>

                   <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/cart"

                      ><i class="uil uil-shopping-cart-alt"></i> Cart</a

                    >
                    <span class="counter" id="cart-count-mobile"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    
    echo $cart_count;
    ?></span>


              </li>
```

This is the same  code repeating 2 times for cart in both large and mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in functions.php use classname instead of id.it will work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
   
    <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();   
    echo $cart_count;
    ?></span>
    
    <?php     
    $fragments['span.counter'] = ob_get_clean();    
    return $fragments;
}
```